# How do I structure my code / mocha tests for generator functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, mocha.js, redux-saga

I started building a react project with [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) that uses [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) as a test framework.

To handle async operations I recently decided to give [react-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) a try. React-saga utilizes [ES6-generator-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). I find this to be a lot easier to test as it saves me some trouble mocking functions.

However I'm having difficulties structuring the tests in a way that produces an output that I find readable. In the [tutorial](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) the developers provide, they use [tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) which basically allows each assertion to produce its own output.
I find this rather nice since I can create an output for each step in the saga.

Is there some way of achieving a similar output with mocha. Creating multiple "it"s doesn't seem to be an options since it would require them to run in a specific order.

The approach of typing what all the steps do as a text for the "it" doesn't seem practical either. The only solution that I could come up with is to create separate it's and calling next on the generator an increasing number of times and asserting on the last value which also isn't really practical especially if some steps fetch data.

As I'm fairly new to javascript I might miss something obvious here. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Edit 08/14: Add example for clarification:

Let's take the example provided in the tutorial:

```js
import { put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { delay } from 'redux-saga'

export function* incrementAsync() {
  // use the call Effect
  yield call(delay, 1000)
  yield put({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
}
```

With tape they test it like this

```js
test('incrementAsync Saga test', (assert) => {
  const gen = incrementAsync()

  assert.deepEqual(gen.next().value, call(delay, 1000), 'message 1')
  assert.deepEqual(gen.next().value, put({type: 'INCREMENT'}), 'message 2')
  assert.deepEqual(gen.next(), { done: true, value: undefined }, 'message 3')

  assert.end()
});
```

When I try to write this for mocha with chai, it would look like this:

```js
describe('incrementAsync', () => {
  it('waits for a second, dispatches \'INCREMENT\' and is done afterwards', () => {
    const gen = incrementAsync()

    expect(gen.next().value).to.deep.equal(call(delay, 1000))
    expect(gen.next().value).to.deep.equal(put({type: 'INCREMENT'})
    expect(gen.next()).to.deep.equal({ done: true, value: undefined });
  })
})
```

While this looks alright for few steps I'd rather not loose the ability to output what I called 'message ' 1 to 3 in the example because if more then a few steps are in the saga the message would get very long.

So what I'm looking for is something like the following which is an anti pattern if I'm not mistaken since each "it" shouldn't rely on a global state that is modified sequentially.

```
describe('incrementAsync', () => {
  var gen;

  before(() => {
    gen = incrementAsync()  
  })

  it('waits for a second', () => {
    expect(gen.next().value).to.deep.equal(call(delay, 1000))
  })
  it('then dispatches \'INCREMENT\'', () => {
    expect(gen.next().value).to.deep.equal(put({type: 'INCREMENT'})
  })
  it('is done afterwards', () => {
    expect(gen.next()).to.deep.equal({ done: true, value: undefined });
  })
})
```

So my question is if there is a nice way of doing this and producing 3 lines of output ideally each with indication if it succeeded or failed?

Comment: It seems that you're confusing test framework with assertion library. Mocha doesn't do assertions. Chai is often used in conjunction with Mocha and it [allows custom assertion messages](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#expect), similarly to Tape. A separate `it` spec for each 'output' is more appropriate. You can generate `it` blocks in batch if typing them manually produces too much boilerplate code. It is not really clear what your case is, some examples of tested code and specs would help.

Comment: I see. There's no such rule that would prevent several `it`s from having 'global' state (it is local for `describe` block context). I would personally go for a single `it` with several expects and no extra labels, unless there are `expect`s may fail with identical error messages and require to follow stack trace line number to learn which assertion has failed.